Ошибка: "*daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037" "*daemon started successfully"
Когда заходишь в Android Studio показывает эту ошибку. Сразу очищаю ошибку. А так вроде всё работает нормально. Но это ошибка появляется периодически. Помогите пожалуйста как можно устранить ошибку.


Какая же это ошибка, если "started successfully"
